# Why doesn't the processes run until the queue is empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, queue

I have a JSON file (consisting of approx. 5000000 objects) which I'm trying to parse with Python . The reading and parsing of the file is straight forward as it's done by one process. While the data is read each object (a dict at this point) is inserted to a multiprocessing Queue, which is then passed to each process I'm running for further processing. However I have noticed that most processes only process some objects each before exiting, as if the queue is empty even when it isn't, which of course results in most of the objects not being processed.

I am able to work around this by sleeping for 10 seconds before starting the next process, however this creates unneccasary delays and I am assuming there is a better way of doing this?

```
INPUT_JSON = "file.json"

def process_start(id,q,lock):
        tGetCount = 0
        with lock:
                while not q.empty():
                        try:
                                o = q.get() # also tried o=q.get_nowait()
                                tGetCount += 1
                                if o['data'] == "someCondition":
                                        someFunction()
                        except queue.Empty:
                                time.sleep(1)
                                continue
        print("Process no. {} parsed {} records. Queue size: {}".format(id,tGetCount,q.qsize()))
)
def queue_dataset():
        cpu_count = 24
        mp_lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
        procs = []
        q = multiprocessing.Queue()

        f = open(INPUT_JSON)
        data = json.load(f)
        f.close()

        # Insert into queue
        tInsertCount = 0
        for obj in data:
                q.put(obj)
                tInsertCount += 1
                if tInsertCount % 100000 == 0:
                        print("Status: Inserted {}".format(tInsertCount))
                        write_log("Status: Inserted {}".format(tInsertCount))

        print("Insertion done")

        for p in range(cpu_count):
                proc = Process(target=process_start, args=(p,q,mp_lock))
                procs.append(proc)
                proc.start()
                time.sleep(10) # Only a couple hundered object processed if program does not sleep 

        for p in procs:
                p.join(timeout=20)

        print("Number of records inserted ({})- current size ({})= parsed: {}".format(tInsertCount,q.qsize(),tInsertCount-q.qsize()))
```

Here is the result when running the program with 1 sec sleep and get_nowait():

```
Process no. 0 parsed 31862 records. Queue size: 5054794
Process no. 1 parsed 33558 records. Queue size: 5021236
Process no. 2 parsed 34426 records. Queue size: 4986810
Process no. 3 parsed 33051 records. Queue size: 4953759
Process no. 4 parsed 34004 records. Queue size: 4919755
Process no. 5 parsed 33755 records. Queue size: 4886000
Process no. 6 parsed 33435 records. Queue size: 4852565
Process no. 7 parsed 33590 records. Queue size: 4818975
Process no. 8 parsed 35165 records. Queue size: 4783810
Process no. 9 parsed 34140 records. Queue size: 4749670
Process no. 10 parsed 27546 records. Queue size: 4722124
Process no. 11 parsed 33684 records. Queue size: 4688440
Process no. 12 parsed 35285 records. Queue size: 4653155
Process no. 13 parsed 32657 records. Queue size: 4620498
Process no. 14 parsed 35163 records. Queue size: 4585335
Process no. 15 parsed 31848 records. Queue size: 4553487
Process no. 16 parsed 33780 records. Queue size: 4519707
Process no. 17 parsed 34900 records. Queue size: 4484807
Process no. 18 parsed 34030 records. Queue size: 4450777
Process no. 19 parsed 32595 records. Queue size: 4418182
Process no. 20 parsed 35333 records. Queue size: 4382849
Process no. 21 parsed 32484 records. Queue size: 4350365
Process no. 22 parsed 34015 records. Queue size: 4316350
Number of records inserted (5086656)- current size (4247227)= parsed: 839429
Process no. 23 parsed 69393 records. Queue size: 4246957
```

When running the program with get_nowait() and 10 sec sleep between each process:

```
Process no. 0 parsed 339800 records. Queue size: 4746856
Process no. 1 parsed 341506 records. Queue size: 4405350
Process no. 2 parsed 334232 records. Queue size: 4071118
Process no. 3 parsed 333835 records. Queue size: 3737283
Process no. 4 parsed 328776 records. Queue size: 3408507
Process no. 5 parsed 332531 records. Queue size: 3075976
Process no. 6 parsed 335032 records. Queue size: 2740944
Process no. 7 parsed 339034 records. Queue size: 2401910
Process no. 8 parsed 343183 records. Queue size: 2058727
Process no. 9 parsed 341165 records. Queue size: 1717562
Process no. 10 parsed 337569 records. Queue size: 1379993
Process no. 11 parsed 345278 records. Queue size: 1034715
Process no. 12 parsed 345037 records. Queue size: 689678
Process no. 13 parsed 334748 records. Queue size: 354930
Process no. 14 parsed 344517 records. Queue size: 10413
Process no. 15 parsed 10413 records. Queue size: 0
Process no. 16 parsed 0 records. Queue size: 0
Process no. 17 parsed 0 records. Queue size: 0
Process no. 18 parsed 0 records. Queue size: 0
Process no. 19 parsed 0 records. Queue size: 0
Process no. 20 parsed 0 records. Queue size: 0
Process no. 21 parsed 0 records. Queue size: 0
Process no. 22 parsed 0 records. Queue size: 0
Process no. 23 parsed 0 records. Queue size: 0
Number of records inserted (5086656)- current size (0)= parsed: 5086656
```

Using get and no sleep:

```
Process no. 0 parsed 255 records. Queue size: 5086401
Process no. 1 parsed 281 records. Queue size: 5086120
Process no. 2 parsed 0 records. Queue size: 5086120
Process no. 3 parsed 7 records. Queue size: 5086113
Process no. 4 parsed 9 records. Queue size: 5086104
Process no. 5 parsed 6 records. Queue size: 5086098
Process no. 6 parsed 1 records. Queue size: 5086097
Process no. 7 parsed 1 records. Queue size: 5086096
Process no. 8 parsed 11 records. Queue size: 5086085
Process no. 9 parsed 6 records. Queue size: 5086079
Process no. 10 parsed 1 records. Queue size: 5086078
Process no. 11 parsed 2 records. Queue size: 5086076
Process no. 12 parsed 1 records. Queue size: 5086075
Process no. 13 parsed 5 records. Queue size: 5086070
Process no. 14 parsed 8 records. Queue size: 5086062
Process no. 15 parsed 5 records. Queue size: 5086057
Process no. 16 parsed 1 records. Queue size: 5086056
Process no. 17 parsed 6 records. Queue size: 5086050
Process no. 18 parsed 0 records. Queue size: 5086050
Process no. 19 parsed 0 records. Queue size: 5086050
Process no. 20 parsed 1 records. Queue size: 5086049
Process no. 21 parsed 1 records. Queue size: 5086048
Process no. 22 parsed 10 records. Queue size: 5086038
Process no. 23 parsed 11322 records. Queue size: 5074716
Number of records inserted (5086656)- current size (5074716)= parsed: 11940
```

Answer (score 0):

First an aside:

A JSON file with a single list consisting of 5_000_000 dictionaries? You need a lot of memory to read that in because you have to read all 5_000_000 dictionaries at once. Why not 5_000_000 lines where each line is a single JSON-encoded dictionary? Then you could read it in with:

```py
def generate_dictionaries():
    with open('file.json') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield json.loads(line)
```

This would be helpful to reduce memory especially if you use the multiprocessing pool I suggest (see last two code exameples).

Now back to your issue:

Method `multiprocessing.Queue.empty` is not reliable (read the docs). Instead, the "writer" should write N *sentinel* objects following the actual data to signify to the N child processes reading from the queue that there is no more data to be processed and so they can now terminate.

**Because of the locking you are doing, even though you created 24 child processes, they are running one at a time. If the call to `queue.empty` was completely reliable, you would never get a True result until the first child process has read and processed *every* item on the queue. The next 23 processes would then report 0 objects processed.**

I have also added some comments to some of the code that is a bit confusing to me. Please read them.

```py
INPUT_JSON = "file.json"

class Sentinel:
    pass

def process_start(id,q,lock):
        tGetCount = 0
        # What is this lock accomplishing here?
        # There is no need to lock queue operations. If a lock must be
        # used to serialize calls to `someFunction`, then do the locking
        # later on. By placing it here your cpu_count processes will not
        # be running in parallel and you are not multiprocessing!!!
        #with lock:
        while True:
            o = q.get() # This will not raise a queue.Empty exception
            if isinstance(o, Sentinel):
                break # There are no more items to get
            tGetCount += 1
            if o['data'] == "someCondition":
                with lock: # if some_function must be called one-at-a-time
                    someFunction()
        print("Process no. {} parsed {} records. Queue size: {}".format(id,tGetCount,q.qsize()))
)

def queue_dataset():
        cpu_count = 24
        mp_lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
        procs = []
        q = multiprocessing.Queue()

        f = open(INPUT_JSON)
        data = json.load(f)
        f.close()

        # Insert into queue
        tInsertCount = 0
        for obj in data:
                q.put(obj)
                tInsertCount += 1
                if tInsertCount % 100000 == 0:
                        print("Status: Inserted {}".format(tInsertCount))
                        write_log("Status: Inserted {}".format(tInsertCount))

        # Add sentinels, one for each subprocess, to show there is no more data to follow:
        sentinel = Sentinel()
        for _ in range(cpu_count):
            q.put(sentinel)

        print("Insertion done")
        

        for p in range(cpu_count):
                proc = Process(target=process_start, args=(p,q,mp_lock))
                procs.append(proc)
                proc.start()
                # I don't understand why this sleep is necessary:
                #time.sleep(10) # Only a couple hundered object processed if program does not sleep 

        for p in procs:
                p.join(timeout=20)

        print("Number of records inserted ({})- current size ({})= parsed: {}".format(tInsertCount,q.qsize(),tInsertCount-q.qsize()))
```

I would suggest that you start the child processes and only then start writing items to the queue. In that way you can overlap the writing and reading from the queue (i.e. increased parallel processing):

```py
...

def queue_dataset():
        cpu_count = 24
        mp_lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
        procs = []
        q = multiprocessing.Queue()

        f = open(INPUT_JSON)
        data = json.load(f)
        f.close()

        for p in range(cpu_count):
                proc = Process(target=process_start, args=(p,q,mp_lock))
                procs.append(proc)
                proc.start()
                # I don't understand why this sleep is necessary:
                #time.sleep(10) # Only a couple hundered object processed if program does not sleep 

        # Insert into queue
        tInsertCount = 0
        for obj in data:
                q.put(obj)
                tInsertCount += 1
                if tInsertCount % 100000 == 0:
                        print("Status: Inserted {}".format(tInsertCount))
                        write_log("Status: Inserted {}".format(tInsertCount))

        # Add sentinels, one for each subprocess, to show there is no more data to follow:
        sentinel = Sentinel()
        for _ in range(cpu_count):
            q.put(sentinel)

        print("Insertion done")

        for p in procs:
                p.join(timeout=20)

        print("Number of records inserted ({})- current size ({})= parsed: {}".format(tInsertCount,q.qsize(),tInsertCount-q.qsize()))
```

If you need the call to sleep because you are exhausting memory, then you could use a multiprocessing pool with the `imap_unordered` method:

```py
INPUT_JSON = "file.json"

def initialize_pool_processes(mp_lock):
    global lock

    lock = mp_lock

def process_object(o):
    """
    Process a single object
    """
    
    if o['data'] == "someCondition":
        with lock: # if some_function must be called one-at-a-time
            someFunction()

def compute_chunksize(pool_size, iterable_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

def queue_dataset():
    cpu_count = 24
    mp_lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    f = open(INPUT_JSON)
    data = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    
    pool = Pool(cpu_count, initializer=initialize_pool_processes, initargs=(mp_lock,))
    # Consider an even smaller chunksize if memory is a problem
    # This computes to be approximately 50_000. You could make it 1_000:
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(cpu_count, len(data))
    worker = partial(process_object, mp_lock)
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(worker, data, chunksize=chunksize):
        pass
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

If you re-create your JSON file as I suggest, then the dictionaries are read in only as pool processes become idle looking for more work:

```py
INPUT_JSON = "file.json"

def initialize_pool_processes(mp_lock):
    global lock

    lock = mp_lock

def process_object(o):
    """
    Process a single object
    """
    
    if o['data'] == "someCondition":
        with lock: # if some_function must be called one-at-a-time
            someFunction()

def generate_dictionaries():
    with open(INPUT_JSON) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield json.loads(line)


def compute_chunksize(pool_size, iterable_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

def queue_dataset():
    cpu_count = 24
    mp_lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    
    pool = Pool(cpu_count, initializer=initialize_pool_processes, initargs=(mp_lock,))
    # Consider an even smaller chunksize if memory is a problem
    # This computes to be approximately 50_000. You could make it 1_000:
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(cpu_count, 5_000_000)
    worker = partial(process_object, mp_lock)
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(worker, generate_dictionaries(), chunksize=chunksize):
        pass
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```